# plugin.xx.view.pluginNamespace = Controller are not allowed by this Plugin

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have started a extension under TYPO3 6.2, and migrated this to TYPO3 7. Now it seems, that all links to Controller/Action combinations are broken.
In my TypoScript I have set:

```
plugin.tx_extensionname.view.pluginNamespace = tx_extensioname
```

In `ext_tables.php` I have set:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Pi1',
    'Controller1: DoSomeLogic1'
);

....

\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'Pi12',
    'Controller12: DoSomeLogic12'
);
```

In `ext_localconf.php` the plugins get configured:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'MRU.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Pi2',
    array(
        'Basket'    => 'list, add, remove, address, setDeliveryCountryJson',
        'Order'     => 'directorder, savedirectorder, accountorder, loginorder, saveloginorder, saveaccountorder, overview, doOrder, paymentSuccess, paymentFailure, paymentNotification, paymentCancel',
        'Payment'   => 'index'
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Basket' => 'list, add, remove, address, setDeliveryCountryJson',
        'Order'     => 'directorder, savedirectorder, accountorder, loginorder, saveloginorder, saveaccountorder, overview, doOrder, paymentSuccess, paymentFailure, paymentNotification, paymentCancel',
        'Payment'   => 'index'
    )
);
```

On a page (id 42) I have placed the plugin Pi2. The Basket Controller is shown with list action. All fine. The URL is like this:

`http://www.example.com/index.php?id=42`

If I add the namespaced Controller Parameter, like this
`http://www.example.com/index.php?id=42&tx_extensionname[controller]=Basket`

I get instantly the

`#1313855173: The controller "Basket" is not allowed by this plugin. Please check for TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() in your ext_localconf.php.`

Exception. If I add the pluginname to the URI like this

`http://www.example.com/index.php?id=42&tx_extensionname_pi2[controller]=Basket`

no expecption is thrown. But if I call a action like this

`http://www.example.com/index.php?id=42&tx_extensionname_pi2[controller]=Basket&tx_extensionname_pi2[action]=add`

this action gets never called. The Controller with it's first action is called.

I did the update some weeks ago, it is only a dev system, but today I cleared all caches and the error occours. Have I missed something with plugin combined namespaces and the registration/configuration/linking of it?

Comment: You say your plugin name is "Pi2", but your URL parameter names end with `_pi1`. Check what happens when changing it to `_pi2`.

Comment: sorry, written wrong here. I called it with pi2, the error occured. Fixed in post above

Comment: Is the difference between plugin names in `registerPlugin` and `configurePlugin` also a typo?

Comment: Yes. In my environment it's equal. These plugins worked for 6 months very well under 6.2 LTS...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that this resolve my issue:

```
plugin.tx_extensionname.mvc.callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 1
```

With `callDefaultActionIfActionCantBeResolved = 0` or missing the above, i get the Not Allowed Exception. Settings this to `1` the Controller and Action gets called.